# How to set Jenkins auth2 credential from String?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, credentials, jenkins-groovy

I'm using the Jenkins [parametrised remote trigger plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/) to call Jenkins server (A) from our Jenkins server (B). It's been working successfully using the Jenkins credential manager, but I'm now wishing to fetch it at run time and then pass in that fetched credential directly as a string, rather than have it stored in Jenkins.

Essentially I'm trying to get a `String` into an `auth2` object to use in my remote trigger.

Existing code:

```java
triggerRemoteJob job: "${REMOTE_JOB}",
        parameters: "REDACTED",
        auth: CredentialsAuth(credentials: "cred-id")
```

What I'm working towards:

```java
def fetchedCred = getFromThirdPartyResource()
triggerRemoteJob job: "${REMOTE_JOB}",
        parameters: "REDACTED",
        auth: CredFromString(fetchedCred)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution really depends on the type of Authentication method you intend to use. Since you are using `CredentialsAuth` I assume you plan on using `Basic Auth`. In `Basic Auth` you will be passing the Authorization header like below

```
Authorization: Basic username:password (username:password will be base64 encoded)
```

So in order to get around your issue, you can use `TokenAuth` instead of `CredentialsAuth`. If you look at the code [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/ParameterizedRemoteTrigger/auth2/TokenAuth.java#L53) `TokenAuth` is also generating a `Basic Auth` header with the provided `apiToken` and `userName`. Hence you can use something like the below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def password = new hudson.util.Secret('admin')
                    def username = 'admin'
                    triggerRemoteJob job: "http://localhost:8080/job/test", auth: TokenAuth(apiToken: password, userName: username)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```